# Highcharts: X-axis off by 2 hours

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am trying to display a dataset that spans 60 minutes, but for some reason the x-axis is constantly off by 2 hours. I am passing through an array of objects, each containing the unix timestamp and a value, `[{ x:1372795260, y:1 } , {...}, {etc...}]`.

What could be causing this, and how can I get it to display the correct time?

I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8zXt/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be a time zone issue
highcharts by default assumes timestamps are supplied in UTC
you may try to using

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

this would make highcharts display data in your browsers timezone